# Time complexity of HashMap/HashTable in case of string elements

Tags: java, hashmap, hashtable

We are running for loop n times, where n is length of words. In case if hashcode of all strings is same, and all strings just differ by last few characters or all strings in words array are same, equals method has to compare almost all characters to check their equality of 2 strings. If k is length of longest/average string, what would be complexity of below code? I'm assuming O(nlogk) if hashmap is internally implemented using balanced binary tree.

```
String[] words = {"cccccb", "cccccb", "ccccbc"};
Map<String, Integer> count = new HashMap();
for (String word: words) {
    count.put(word, count.getOrDefault(word, 0) + 1);
}
```

Comment: Hashtable/map is different from a binary tree. And String.hashcode will use all the characters in the string to create its hashcode - this is how it is implemented, and is the right way to create semi-unique hashcodes

Comment: 'Balanced binary tree' is actually not definitive enough to answer your question. There are dozens of ways of producing balanced binary trees and they have different complexities. The openjdk implementation of `HashMap` is quite sophisticated with a couple of algorithms depending on the number of clashes. Also note `count.merge(word, 1, Integer::sum)` might be a slightly more elegant and efficient alternative.

Comment: Assuming n is the number of strings in words, and k is the average string length, then it's O(nk).  Each call to `count.put` and `count.getOrDefault` is O(k) if the hash value is (re)calculated from the string on the fly, or O(1) if precalculated (I'm not sure which Java does).  Note hash table are a different data structure from a balanced binary tree - you'd do well to google "hash table".  (If you had used a balanced binary tree, it would have been O(log(n) k)).